# Javadoc errors on @link to a generic

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

Using Java 1.8.0_144 and it seems that Javadoc chokes on an @link to a generic defined in a superclass, here is some example code that shows the issue:

```
/**
 * Basic demo class
 *
 * @param <T>
 *            An explanation on the generic
 */
public abstract class AbsTest<T> {
    /**
     * Basic demo method
     * 
     * @param someParam
     *            What to do magic on. See {@link T#toString()}
     */
    public abstract void doMagic(T someParam);
}
```

That class will work fine, the problem starts when we add the implementation:

```
/**
 * Basic impl class
 */
public class ImplTest extends AbsTest<Object> {
    @Override
    public void doMagic(Object someParam) {
        // Magic happens
    }
}
```

Eclipse is perfectly happy, but Javadoc now fails with:

```
org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeVariableSymbol cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol
```

The cause of the problem seems to be "{@link T#toString()}" in the superclass and manifests when there is *any* subclass. Is this a bug in the Javadoc or am I breaking some Javadoc standard?

Comment: The error message itself is a bug in the sense that even if the Javadoc does not comply to specs the code should show a more helpful message instead of failing with a low level cast exception.

Comment: In any case have you tried ```AbsTest#doMagic(T)``` instead? What about ```{@link ...}``` instead of  ```@see```.

Comment: If the T or Object part is the issue you don't need to include them since there is only one doMagic. So try ```AbsTest#doMagic```  on its own. Don't know about ```@see``` but with ```{@link }``` you can indicate the text for the link: e.g. ```{@link AbsTest#doMagic AbsTest.doMagic(Object)}```

Comment: {@link T} fails as well.

Sorry Valentin, I don't understand your second comment. Production code is much more complex, the above is just a stripped-down example. The original developer attempted to use "{@link T}" which was initially OK, then Javadoc failed as soon as there was a subclass. I have tried to clarify the original question.

Comment: I had just tested the source code that you provide with a fresh download of 1.8.0_144 and there is no exceptions when I run javadoc from the command on those two classes. Can you provide the exact formula to produce the exception... can you figure out the exact javadoc command command maven is invoking to get that exception

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'd missed out "#toString()" (I just needed an example method) from the Javadocs in the superclass. As for command, I'm actually doing it via Maven but a basic execution also shows the issue: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javadoc.exe" path\to\source\*.java

Answer (score 0):

`T` could be declared to be something like `<T extends I1 && I2 && I3>`, meaning `T` has to conform to all three interfaces.
If the same function signature is in multiple interfaces (say, `I1` and `I3`, which is valid!), Javadoc won't know if the link should go to `I1` or `I3` the link should go to, so it does not implement links to members of generics.
(There's also the understanding that generics aren't first-class citizens of the type system, and maybe that contributed to the decision not to deal with links to generics in Javadoc. That said, they *could* have added syntax for such cases, but they did not.)

But you can write a link to the type bound of the parameter. I.e. for `T extends I1`, you can write `I1#foo`.
In the case of `toString`, that's in `Object`, which your class is a subclass of, so you can just write `#toString`.
Fine point: you could write `Object#toString()` to indicate that you don't mean `this.toString()` but `someParam.toString()`. But I believe this kind of subtle hint is lost on most maintainers; it's probably better to write `{@code someParam.}{link #toString()}`.